# How can you add a unique id to each instance of a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I want to add a unique ID to each div in this directive, so that I can specify what element that google maps should pass:

```
directive('gMap', function(googleMaps){
return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div id="{{unique_ID}}"></div><div ng-transclude></div>",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){


            //create the map
            var center = googleMaps.makePosition(attrs.centerlat, attrs.centerlong)
            //update map on load
            var options = googleMaps.setMapOptions(center, attrs.zoom);
            scope.map = googleMaps.createMap(options, unique_id)    
        },
    };
}).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directive template unique IDs for elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021951/directive-template-unique-ids-for-elements)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the unique id of the directive's scope.

```
<div id="gMap-{{::$id}}"></div><div ng-transclude></div>
```

`scope.$id` return an unique number that monotonically increase for each scope instance.

The '::' is to use the one-time binding if you use angular 1.3 or later.

See [Angular scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that these IDs will remain unique even when the elements attached to these IDs are destroyed or recreated dynamically? What I mean is, if at a given time `$id = 26` and the element carrying this ID is destroyed, will `$id = 26` ever be generated again even if the same element is recreated?

Comment: According to the [$rootScope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), the $id is monotonically increasing. So yes, the $id will be unique over the time as long you dont destroy the $rootScope.

Comment: Be aware that `ng-if` creates a new scope.  I had a child element `.tooltip-{{::$id}}` but it had a different id than expected because of this fact.

Answer (score 26):

A simple solution to not introduce a bunch of extra code is to just use `Date.now()`

Would generate for example: `1397123701418`

Answer (score 5):

Add a service that is responsible to return unique id's.

Example:

```
angular.module("app").service("UniqueIdService", function(){

    var nextId = 1;

    this.getUniqueId = function(){
        return nextId++;
    }
});
```

And then simply inject this service into your directive and call it to get a unique id:

```
directive('gMap', function(googleMaps, UniqueIdService){
return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div id="{{unique_ID}}"></div><div ng-transclude></div>",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.unique_ID = UniqueIdService.getUniqueId();

            //create the map
            var center = googleMaps.makePosition(attrs.centerlat, attrs.centerlong)
            //update map on load
            var options = googleMaps.setMapOptions(center, attrs.zoom);
            scope.map = googleMaps.createMap(options, scope.unique_ID)    
        },
    };
}).
```