# when the sameAngular JS directive is two times on a view, they share the same scope scope even with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, directive

I have created a directive that works fine when is alone on a template, but when is written twice or more time, only functions of the first written are called

```
<dlg-rating changed="rateChanged()" rate="object1.averageRate"></dlg-rating>
<dlg-rating changed="imageRatingChanged()" rate="object2.rating"></dlg-rating>
```

first works fine, and when object1.averageRate change,  rateChanged() is called.

When object2.rating changes, rateChanged() is called instead of imageRatingChanged()

the directive is:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('dlgRating', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl:'modules/directives/rating.html',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            rate: '=',
            changed: '&'
        }
    };
});
```

and the template is:

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="10"/>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="9"/>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="8"/>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="7"/>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="6"/>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="5"/>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="4"/>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="3"/>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="2"/>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" ng-click="changed()" ng-model="rate" value="1"/>
</fieldset>
```

why the scope is not isolated and it always uses the function of the first written

in the controller

```
$scope.object1 = {...};
$scope.object1.averageRate = 2;
$scope.object2 = {...};
$scope.object2.rating = 5;

$scope.rateChanged = function() {
  console.log('rate changed');
}

$scope.imageRatingChanged = function() {
  console.log('image rating changed');
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `>` bracket in your first use of the directive. Is that just a copy and paste error?

Comment: yep, just a copy paste error. thanks

Comment: Please add the code for `rateChanged()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yujuiting/ry6rLax2/  I didn't see any problem?

Comment: here you are, but i think it is not rhe problem

Comment: @yujuiting you are right, it work fine. i will revise my code because im sure it is the same. thank you very much

Comment: I copied your code into a jsfiddle and it appears to work just fine. Perhaps the error is elsewhere: https://jsfiddle.net/kL5y49sy/   (btw, you shouldn't be using the `id` attribute inside a template without making the value an expression otherwise you will get duplicate ids in the DOM. That isn't the problem here but could give other issues)

Comment: @Duncan actually it can be the problem,  isnt it ?  I use the id with labels with icons (stars) and titles and it may be hidding the problem (the radios are hidden)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021951/directive-template-unique-ids-for-elements

Comment: the id were the problem. using  id="starhalf_{{$id}}" with the labels makes that all work properly.

but... why the error of the duplicate id do not appear in the inspector console of the browser?